# Reuse a Button template that needs parameters

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, datatemplate

I have several buttons that I have setup like this:

```
<Button Template="{DynamicResource btnTmplt}" Command="{Binding ImgChgeCmd}" >
  <Button.Resources>
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="btnTmplt" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" 
                Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image x:Name="img" Source=""></Image>
    </StackPanel>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
          <Trigger.Setters>
            <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" 
Here--------->      Value="{Binding FirstImage, Converter={StaticResource GrayScaleConverter}}" />
            <Setter TargetName="stPanel" Property="BitmapEffect">
              <Setter.Value>
                <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="1" />
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Trigger.Setters>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
          <Trigger.Setters>
And Here--> <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{Binding FirstImage}" />
            <Setter TargetName="stPanel" Property="BitmapEffect" Value="{x:Null}" />
          </Trigger.Setters>
        </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

The Button.Resources section is almost the same in all of these buttons.  The two lines that are different are the Value bindings indicated by the "Here--->" above.

These differences allow me to load a different image for each button.

**Is there a way to set this up so that I don't have to duplicate the Button.Resources for each button?**  (But still load a different image in each button).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom control.  I have done a simple example but you can customise the control to behave however you want (it is very powerful).  Also please take care that the BitMapEffects have been deprecated and if you try and use them in .net 4 you will get an exception.  Anyway...Create a custom control like:

```
public class VaccanoButton : Button
{        
    static VaccanoButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(VaccanoButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(VaccanoButton)));
    }

    public ImageSource FirstImage
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(FirstImageProperty); }   
        set { SetValue(FirstImageProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FirstImage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FirstImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(VaccanoButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));  
}
```

and set up the xaml in the Generic.xaml like: (NB: I took out your GrayScaleConverter because I don't have the code for it, just put it back in as a resource and it should work)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:VaccanoButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:VaccanoButton}">
                <Button>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="stPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto"  
                Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="img"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=FirstImage}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="stPanel" Property="BitmapEffect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="1"  />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=FirstImage}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="stPanel" Property="BitmapEffect" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </Trigger.Setters>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and then use it like:

```
        <local:VaccanoButton FirstImage="\Untitled.png"/>
```